# inequality based on Hermite polynomial

Tags: special-functions

> How to prove that 
>   $$|H_n(x)| \leq |H_n(ix)|?$$

I have tried with the explicit representation of the Hermite polynomial, but can't reach the target. Any clue please.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint** : it just has to do with the fact that $H_n(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor} (-1)^kc_{n, k} x^{n-2k}$ for some $c_{n, k}\geq 0$.

Comment: $H_n(ix)=\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]} (-1)^k C_{n,k}(ix)^{n-2k}=i^{n}\sum_{k=0}^{[n/2]} C_{n,k}x^{n-2k}$

Comment: Yes ? What happens if x is positive ? Negative ?

Comment: So, is it $i^n H_n(x)=H_n(ix)$ or not?

Comment: I know this is a very old post, but has anyone a proof or a reference for the fact illustrated by Sary?